# copying multiple cell contents into a single cell

Tags: excel, google-sheets

Is there a formula that can do the following:

Copy all the contents on column A, rows 1 to 4, into a new cell, and separate the contents using a new line.

Example input:

```
       | A                |
Row 1  | Alpha Beta Omega |
Row 2  |                  |
Row 3  | 21321 Cri Je     |
Row 4  | Cappa NF B       |
```

Example output:

```
Row 5 | Alpha Beta Omega
        21321 Cri Je
        Cappa NF B        |
```

Comment: `=A1&CHAR(10)&A2&CHAR(10)&A3&CHAR(10)&A4`, remember to also `Wrap Text`.

Comment: While Excel and Google Sheets have similar features there are some that aren't the same, so choose one app. By the other hand, please add a brief description of your search/research efforts.

Answer (score 1):

For Google sheets,

```
=JOIN(CHAR(10),FILTER(A1:A4,A1:A4<>""))
```

For Google sheets as well as Excel 2016 (w/Office365),

```
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),1,A1:A4)
```